# EPERM error occurs while building Next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js13, build-error

I can't build the app made in next.js. I get this error:

```
uncaughtException [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\\lessions\\Next.js\\next-ts\\.next\\trace'] {
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'D:\\lessions\\Next.js\\next-ts\\.next\\trace'        
}
```

Comment: First run "npm run build" and then run "npm start".